# ¿Como puedo combinar 2 metodos GET?

Tags: java, spring

Tengo 2 metodos `get` utilizo springboot y el primero me trae a todas las personas activas `boolean active` y el segundo a los contactos que tiene la persona, pero necesito que me traiga esos `contactos` segun si estan activos o no, gracias

```
@GetMapping("/personemergencycontacts")
public List<PersonEmergencyContact> getAllActive() {
    List<PersonEmergencyContact> lista = service.findAllByActive();
    return lista;
}

@GetMapping("/personemergencycontacts/person/{id}")
public List<PersonEmergencyContact> getPersonEmergencyContactByPersonId(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long PersonEmergencyContactId) {
    List<PersonEmergencyContact> lista = service.findByPersonId(PersonEmergencyContactId);
    return lista;
}
```

Repositorio

```
public interface PersonEmergencyContactRepository extends CrudRepository<PersonEmergencyContact, Long> {

@Query("SELECT p FROM PersonEmergencyContact p WHERE p.active = 1")

List<PersonEmergencyContact> findAllByActive();

List<PersonEmergencyContact> findByPersonId(Long id);
```

}

Servicio, solo los list relevantes en esté caso

```
@Override
public List<PersonEmergencyContact> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}

public List<PersonEmergencyContact> findAllByActive() { return dao.findAllByActive(); }

public List<PersonEmergencyContact> findByPersonId(Long PersonEmergencyContactId) { return dao.findByPersonId(PersonEmergencyContactId); }

public void softDelete(Long Id) {
    PersonEmergencyContact personemergencycontact = this.findById(Id);
    personemergencycontact.setDeleted_at(toISO8601UTC(new Date()));
    personemergencycontact.setActive(false);
    this.update(personemergencycontact);
}
```

}

y el soft delete que cambia el campo `active`(default 1) a `0`

Comment: No está clara la relación de ambas listas, ¿puedes aclararlo un poco?

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el código de tu método `service.findByPersonId()`? Por como lo veo no necesitas relacionar ambas listas si desde `findByPersonId()` puedes traer solo los que están activos

Comment: es que no tengo una relaicon entre ambas, eso necesitaria hacer, ahora agrego el servicio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el get

@GetMapping("/personemergencycontacts/person/{id}")

Puede quedar tu metodo:

```
public List<PersonEmergencyContact> getPersonEmergencyContactByPersonId(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long PersonEmergencyContactId) {
 List<PersonEmergencyContact> lista= new ArrayList<PersonEmergencyContact>();
 List<PersonEmergencyContact> lista2 = service.findByPersonId(PersonEmergencyContactId);
  for (PersonEmergencyContact otro : lista2 ){
    if(otro.getActive().equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
      lista.add(otro);
     }
  }
  return lista;
}
```

getActive(), debes agregarlo en tu clase PersonEmergencyContact como:

public String getActive() {
         return Active;
     }

Ajustalo a tu modelo

Comment: por que me marcara errores en el new ArrayList y equalsIgnore, yo tengo un bolean  public boolean isActive() { return active; }

Comment: agrega el import java.util.*; se agrega el equals en caso de que sea string pero como el tuyo es booleano con un == es suficiente

Comment: gracias, ahi quedo, espero poder realizar aportes a esta tremenda comunidad

Comment: Fue un placer haberte ayudado y bienvenido